# Is starting session_start this way more secure?

Tags: php, session

A friend of mine starts his Session this way.

```
<?php
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION);
session_start();
?>
```

Are there any security advantages, against Session hijacking etc.

Just wondering why as against the usual session_start();

Comment: where did you find this code?

Comment: If you do it this way, you will start new session each request, that is not good.

Comment: This code deletes the session then makes a new empty one each time it's ran.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought so too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you'd need is

```
session_start()
session_regenerate_id()
```

That'll start the session and change its ID on each request. However, this will not prevent session hijacking. If the attacker can get the user's session cookie and sent a request back to the server BEFORE the user can, then the attacker gets a brand new session ID, and the user is left with an invalid session token and is effectively logged out.

Answer (score 2):

If this code is found at the top of every page on a given site, there will be no session that is maintained between post backs and different pages. If you want to use SESSION as server-side storage for data that you're not going to use across post backs or multiple pages then I suppose it may be viable, but that would make for a very odd and most likely poorly developed application.

What it looks like your friend may have been trying to do is wipe out any previous SESSION information and then start a new one. Perhaps he is checking against some quantifier and if it evaluates properly then including this in a PHP page? In any case calling Rocket's functions work better.

Answer (score 0):

This code deletes the session then makes a new empty one each time it's ran.

```
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION);
```

This will remove all data in your session, then `session_start` will make you a brand new one.

You can run this the 1st time to make a new session, but if you want to have the data in the session on other page loads, you just need `session_start`.